# Если сменить MAC-адрес

Tags: linux, windows, tcp-ip, железо, mac-address

Если сменить MAC-адрес, то интернет-провайдер будет считать, что это новенький компьютер подключился или как?

Comment: Ну объясните кто-нибудь мне

Comment: Я не уверен, но мне кажется, что провайдеру все равно на Ваш `MAC`. Он будет идентифицировать Вас по `IP`.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81

Comment: Вообще-то зависит от провайдера и способа авторизации.

Comment: меня интересует если сменить mac-адрес то для провайдера автоматом это новый комп?
т.е. пойти в магазин купить новый комп и полючиться из дома и он такой опа новый комп... - это тоже самое будет если сменить mac-адрес для провайдера?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Можно подробнее о способах и т.д?

Comment: Провайдеру нет дела до ваших компьютеров внутри локальной сети. Он их вообще никак не идентифицирует.

Comment: Провайдер не видит и не может видеть число хостов в твоей локальной (домашней) сети. Все их знания о твоей сети заканчиваются на твоем маршрутизаторе. Для полного понимания как все работает пройди курс CCNA, думаю загуглиш

Comment: @Beast Winterwolf  Да вот не всегда, многие провайдеры привязываются к mac адресу, например 2КОМ, Rinet. это из тех с кем имел дело.

Answer (score 1):

Со стороны провайдера, ваше подключение идентифицируется по порту на оборудовании, мак- или айпи-адрес - это свойства устройства на том конце порта. Оборудование, которое стоит у большинства провайдеров сегодня, позволяет определять смену мак-адреса, но свойство мак-адреса может быть важно для одного провайдера и неважно для другого, поэтому если вы смените мак-адрес, то один провайдер будет идентифицировать устройство на том конце как новое и вы потеряете доступ в Интернет, а другой нет и доступ сохранится (если сохраните настройки TCP/IP протоколов).

Comment: Большинство недоморощенных провайдеров покупают оборудование  с поддержкой VLAN тегирования, как вы и написали.

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаю, как работает Ваш конкретный провайдер, но из личной практики (Дома локалка, с выходом в иНет через маршрутизатор) могу сказать:

1. Внутри локалки можно резвиться как угодно. Установленный на маршрутизаторе DHCP сервер самостоятельно решает все проблемы.
2. Если покупается новый маршрутизатор с новым МАС-адресом, то иНет отрубается и нужно звонить провайдеру, называть номер договора и объяснять ситуацию. Он востанавливает доступ в иНет.